# Firefox Extension: close event on popup

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

guys!

I am writing web extension for Firefox.

I need to handle close event on popup window of extension (specifically, like beforeClosed) to save data, which user set in form.

How can I do this?

Comment: You will find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047924/firefox-extension-onpopupclose-event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
window.addEventListener("unload", function(){
  console.log("save your data");
});
```

Source:
[Firefox Extension - onPopupClose event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047924/firefox-extension-onpopupclose-event)

Answer (score 1):

YMMV, but the accepted answer did not work for me. The 'unload' event never fired. What did work was 'blur', placed in a JS file that is loaded by the popup HTML file.

```
window.addEventListener('blur', function (event) {
  console.log('Window closing.');
});
```

Comment: Interesting approach! It seems to fire ~0.2s before `unload` event. But unlike `unload`, it can fire multiple times (not when closing, but while opened when user "blur" window - for me dragging elements seems to trigger it).