# Firefox Extension - onPopupClose event?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have popup in which I need to update the data inside it in reactively. What function or event is needed to track when a popup closes?

Currently my code structure is as follows:

```js
let BG = browser.extension.getBackgroundPage();
let timer = BG.timer;

function updatePageTime(secondsElapsed) {
    const content = document.getElementById("content");
    content.innerHTML = "Current Time Spent: " + timer.getTimeElapsed();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    timer.subscribe(updatePageTime);
});

document.addEventListener("unload", function () {
    timer.unsubscribe(updatePageTime);
});
```

The problem is that unload and beforeunload do not trigger on popup closes, thus I am unable to stop updates to a non-existant DOM.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I did not see that unload is defined on window and not document. Simply changing the `document.addEventListener("unload"` to `window.addEventListener("unload"` fixes the problem.