# Firefox WebExtension popup - 'click' event functional, but 'unload' is not working (instead, 'blur' works fine)

Tags: popupwindow, firefox-addon-webextensions, dom-events

When I change "unload" to "blur" its working (unfortunately - even when I take away focus only from the button calling "scroll" function). I want "stopScrolling" to be executed after user closes (clicks outside) the popup window. I've also tried "beforeunload" event, which is also not functional. Below is the crippled version of the code:

```
function scroll(tabs) {
    browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
        command: "scroll",
    })
}

function stopScrolling(tabs) {
    browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
        command: "stop",
    })
}

function reportError(error) {
    console.error(`Could not execute: ${error}`)
}


function init() {        
    window.addEventListener("unload", () => {
        browser.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true })
            .then(stopScrolling)
            .catch(reportError)
    })
    window.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        browser.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true })
            .then(scroll)
            .catch(reportError)
    })
}

function reportExecuteScriptError(error) {
    document.querySelector("#popup-content").classList.add("hidden")
    document.querySelector("#not-received-msg").classList.remove("hidden")
    document.querySelector("#not-received-msg").textContent = "Script error!"
    console.error(`Failed to execute content script: ${error.message}`)
}

browser.tabs.executeScript({ file: "bcgscript.js" })
    .then(init)
    .catch(reportExecuteScriptError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with alternative solution which is not what I want (if there is any other):

```
window.addEventListener("blur", (e) => {
    if(e.target == window)
        browser.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true })
            .then(stopScrolling)
            .catch(reportError)
})
```

I see https://stackoverflow.com/users/8665598/alex-goico applied "unload" event here [Firefox Extension - onPopupClose event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047924/firefox-extension-onpopupclose-event) and said it works.